# Scanning single project in .NET solution with multiple projects using SonarQube

Tags: .net, msbuild, sonarqube, azure-devops, vstest

I have the following issue.

We have a .NET solution which contains several projects and have created a VSTS build definition per project because we don't want to build the entire solution every time there's a change in one of the individual projects.

Of course in this case when using SonarQube we would only want to push the metrics of that particular project / buildefinition to the SonarQube server and not of the entire solution. 
By default the latter is what's happening and that is what we want to change.

We are using VSTS with Visual Studio 2015, SonarQube plugin version 4.1.1 and SonarQube version 6.7 (build 33306). The buildagents are running on Windows 8.1 at this time.

Example solution structure:

MainSolution

- ProjectA
- ProjectB
- ProjectC

The root sources directory for VSTS in this case is `C:\buildagent\vsts-agent\_work\19\s`

Directory structure on build agent would look like this:

```
C:\buildagent\vsts-agent\_work\19\s\ProjectA
C:\buildagent\vsts-agent\_work\19\s\ProjectB
C:\buildagent\vsts-agent\_work\19\s\ProjectC
```

Let's say we have a VSTS build definition for ProjectB which only builds ProjectB.  In that case we only want to SonarQube to scan the contents of the ProjectB project.

I've tried several things to accomplish this but none of them worked.

1. sonar.inclusions / sonar.exclusions
   Only seems to work on file level, not directory or project. Tried several settings and no error occurs but everything is ignored by the scanner which results in nothing being pushed to SQ 
   server at all.
2. sonar.sources

Setting the property sonar.sources to `C:\buildagent\vsts-agent\_work\19\s\ProjectB` looked promising but we got the error message below when running the scanner:

> 2018-04-04T07:12:51.0538120Z INFO: Base dir: C:\buildagent\vsts-agent_work\19\s
>   2018-04-04T07:12:51.0538120Z INFO: Working dir: C:\buildagent\vsts-agent_work\19.sonarqube\out.sonar
>   2018-04-04T07:12:51.0538120Z INFO: Source paths: ProjectB
>   2018-04-04T07:12:51.0548120Z INFO: Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: nl_NL
>   2018-04-04T07:12:51.1518136Z ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   2018-04-04T07:12:51.1518136Z ERROR: File ProjectB/App.config can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files

It looks like SonarQube is trying to index ProjectB twice. Once with BaseDir set to `C:\buildagent\vsts-agent\_work\19\s\ProjectB` 
and once with BaseDir set to `C:\buildagent\vsts-agent\_work\19\s`

3. sonar.projectBaseDir

When setting the property sonar.projectBaseDir to C:\buildagent\vsts-agent_work\19\s\ProjectB we receive below error from SonarQube.

> 2018-04-04T07:00:51.2906744Z ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   2018-04-04T07:00:51.2906744Z ERROR: Dir C:\buildagent\vsts-agent_work\19\s\ProjectA should be relative to project baseDir

It looks like it is still trying to scan the entire VSTS root source directory `C:\buildagent\vsts-agent\_work\19\s` and not just `C:\buildagent\vsts-agent\_work\19\s\ProjectB`.

So the question remains. How can we make this work?

Comment: Do you have a build definition to build all project, or use separate build definitions to build the project separately? If you use separate build definitions, there won't have the problem. If you have only one build definition, how do you build the projects separately?

Comment: We are using a seperate build definition for each project in a solution.

Comment: If you use 3 build definitions for the 3 project separately, each build should analysis for only one project. Assume this is build definition only build for projectB (app2) https://ibb.co/fWc8Mn, then sonarqube will only analysis app2 https://ibb.co/bQiR7S.

Comment: Yeah, the root source dir C:\buildagent\vsts-agent\_work\19\ contains not only the sources for the one project but for the entire solution in which the project resides. At the beginning of the build def. all solution sources are downloaded to the root source dir because the project might have a dependency with one or more of the other projecst in the solution.

Comment: Yes, all projects will be downloaded in Get sources step at the beginning of  build. Do you also manage the projects build artifacts in your repo? For this situation, SQ will analysis all projects. Else SQ will only analysis the built project if the build artifacts are not manage in your repo. So another way to analysis built project is ignoring the artifacts in your repo.

Answer (score 1):

We've made the decision to split up solutions with multiple projects into multiple solutions and base our VSTS build definitions on single solutions instead of projects. That is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube doesn't support updating only some of the metrics in a SonarQube project - if you have MSBuild projects A, B and C that are all built in a solution and pushed to SonarQube X, then you can't then just build A and push its updated metrics.

You have a couple of options:

- don't run analysis as part of your per-MSBuild-project VSTS build definitions. Instead, run a nightly build of the whole solution and run the analysis as part of that build.
- push each MSBuild project to a separate SonarQube project. That would allow you to push metrics on each build, but you'd lose the aggregated view over your projects. If you are using the Enterprise Edition of SonarQube then you could use the Portfolio Management feature to get a consolidated view over those SonarQube projects.

Comment: The first option will probably work but that way we won't be able to use the Quality Gate failure option with our regular build defs in VSTS right?
The second point you mention is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish but what I cannot get to work.